# VB.net Cross-form Cross-thread form call?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project which requires a separate form which is running a server thread to access and change another forms control location. I know how to call a control from another thread running on the same form but I'm not sure how to do it on a separate form and thread.

Comment: Without seeing some code it would be hard to say.

Comment: I'm running a UdpClient on a separate thread which is running on a form named Server, I want to say change the title of the Form 'Main' from the separate thread on the form named Server.

Comment: Server form could raise an event that form Main is listening for. You will need to delegate the work back to the UI thread still.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can also provide the new location for the control that I want to move doing that.

Comment: An event can be defined with parameters.

Comment: Either use an event as @OneFineDay suggests (recommended), or pass a reference to the main form into your server form.  Do you know how to define a custom event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example...

Define the event in your server form, and raise it when appropriate:

```
Public Class frmServer

    Public Event NewPosition(ByVal pt As Point)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' ... in response to something (probably not a button click!) ...
        Dim x As Integer = 250
        Dim y As Integer = 100
        RaiseEvent NewPosition(New Point(x, y))
    End Sub

End Class
```

In your main form, subscribe to that event when you create an instance of the server form.  This can be done with the `AddHandler` statement and the `AddressOf` keyword.  Then do the normal `Invoke` pattern to make sure it runs in the correct UI thread:

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim server As New frmServer
        AddHandler server.NewPosition, AddressOf server_NewPosition
        server.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub dlgNewPosition(ByVal pt As Point)

    Private Sub server_NewPosition(pt As Point)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New dlgNewPosition(AddressOf server_NewPosition), New Object() {pt})
        Else
            Me.Location = pt
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```